# Connecting multi monitors and improving productivity

Tags: multiple-monitors, desktop-computer

I have a Dell Vostro 260s (slim Fit) CPU and running Win 7 professional edition with it.

Just curious to know,whether I can connect multiple monitors with it.

I googled and found that we need to buy a Video card to connect two monitors.

But, I see that on my CPU's back I have a HDMI port.

Will be it of any help to connect the second monitor ? Or in simple words, how to connect a second monitor with DELL VOSTRO desktop 260s ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your laptop has 2 video outputs (hdmi, dvi, vga) regardless of the combination, you technically should be able to hook up more than one monitor.  If you have your screen that is attached to the laptop AND only one of those outputs then you'd just be able to hook one other monitor up besides the screen attached to the laptop.  If you're trying to attach more than that then you'd need to have a 2nd display port available which generally comes from a more powerful video card but I'm not sure how cheap or possible it is to put a video card in a laptop let alone a slim? (sounds smaller, probably less options if any).

My laptop has a function button that lets me switch between different options.  FN + f7 I think it is.  Anyway, there's 3 options for mine when I hit the button 3 times.  One just has the laptop screen on, one turns the secondary monitor on, and one turns both of them on at the same time.  After this, once you have both screens on, you have to go into your settings on the computer, where you set the resolution (right click desktop -> screen resolution) and setup the screens to be whatever resolution you want.  Also on that same screen, if you click on the monitors shown (1 and 2) and drag them from left to right you can tell windows where the monitors are physically setup from each other.  This way your mouse moves off the screen the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for that. But, could you guide me how exactly could I connect a second monitor with my dell vostro 260s desktop machine? I have currently a vga(already finished) and an unused hdmi ?

Comment: My bad, for some reason when I initially did a google search for that model it came up as a laptop.  Could have been my cookies or I typed something wrong.  When you plug in the hdmi cable into both the monitor and the video card, it should turn the second monitor on automatically.  Guessing it's not doing that, or waited to try it maybe?

Comment: Thanks Codezilla.. But, I have a vga monitor....

Comment: The only way to do what you're trying to do with that monitor is to get an hdmi to vga adapter (search google for that phrase), many local stores possibly walmart/bestbuy will carry them but you could probably find a cheaper one online.

Comment: As a side note, my video card came with an adapter.  I wonder if maybe your pc came with one too?